# What are the minor and major arcs in the Circle method (Hardy & Littlewood)?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I was wondering if somebody would be so kind as to graphically show what are the minor and major arcs in the Circle method?

In this [example](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/250371477_Introduction_to_the_circle_method_of_Hardy_Ramanujan_and_Littlewood), extract below, I've attempted a simple diagram to show what is going on but it is clearly incomplete (I've now edited it to reflect comments).

***Extract problem:***
given $k \in \mathbb{N}$, determine the number of possible representations of n $\in$ N as a sum of exactly $k$ natural numbers.
[image]
Please correct the diagram below and show the major and minor arcs.
[image: circle]

Comment: You say $\rho<1$, yet you've drawn $1$ within the circle $\gamma(\rho)$ which I presume has centre $0$ and radius $\rho$.

Comment: maybe they need swapping around?